# Is there a better way to compare against many strings with like?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of words I need to compare against.
As an example fruit and vegetables that needs to be stored cold vs warmer:

```
Cold
  strawberries
  raspberries
  lettuce


Warm(er)
  cucumber 
  bell pepper 
  tomatoes
```

I have a sheet with products and need to loop it:

```
 For Each cel In rng
    If LCase(cel.Value) Like "*strawberries*" Or LCase(cel.Value) Like "*raspberries*" Or LCase(cel.Value) Like "*lettuce*" Then
        msgbox "Cold"
    ElseIf LCase(cel.Value) Like "*cucumber*" or LCase(cel.Value) Like "*bell pepper*" or LCase(cel.Value) Like "*tomato*" Then
        msgbox "Warmer" 
    End If
Next cel
```

Is there any way I could this better? The syntax to test against all products will be very very long.
Could I somehow group/list them and make the syntax easier to maintain?

Example of the workbook:
[image]

Comment: If you'd store the options in an array you could use Match with wildcards. Also, would it always be either warm or cold? Can it never fall outside  any of those two options? Are wildcards even needed btw? You sample data shows perfect matches.

Comment: yes wildcards is needed. It could be "tomatoes 5kg", "cocktail tomatoes" and so on. The "data sample" was more a list of the search terms and how they group. The actual data in the range has weights, color and all kind of words mixed in there. Not sure I know what Match with wildcards mean... And it could fall outside. Say oranges could be stored both cold and "warm", but those are not interesting

Comment: vlookup? Obviously for this to work you need to prepare the worksheet beforehand. Col A with the Fruits/vegtables. ColB Will have Cold/Warmer...

Comment: @SiddharthRout hmmm.. I want to loop the workbook (image attached in q), and fuzzy match the name column. If the name matches warm, then look at the location of the pallet, is it placed warm or cold. If cold inform user. It needs to run in a xlam file since the workbook is extracted from the management system. "all" of that works fine, I just need a easier to maintain syntax to match the product against warm/cold or (doesn't matter).

Comment: `and fuzzy match the name... ` My comment now becomes irrelevant after your detailed comment. And hence it is important to always include complete details in your question :) The problem with fuzzy logic in your case where the name is combined with say measurements is that it can create false positives for example `Green Apple 1KG` and 
`Green peas 250 gms` Can't use just Green word for a search. Or how the code should know to search for `Green Apple` and not `Green Apple 1KG` since you have other entries which do not have any measurements. Contd...

Comment: Possible to separate the names and measurements into separate columns? If yes, then you can build a unique master list of Fruits/Veggies over a period of time and then you can use that list against your data. If you think, I have still not understood your query then do let me know.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I believe you have understood it. And the issues I'm facing :-) I don't think I can separate them, not in a way that i know for sure it will be correct. And it's not only measurements and colors that create issues. "Asparagus" needs to be cold but "asparagus potatoes" is potatoes that is thin and, well they should be stored cold, but we don't force it since they generally don't stay in the wearhouse long anyways

Comment: `"Asparagus" needs to be cold but "asparagus potatoes" is potatoes that is thin and, well they should be stored cold` Exactly my point! So you cannot search for just `*Asparagus*` :)

Comment: No. Correct. I solved that with search for asparagus then search again in the same string for potatoes. But I know there will be false matches. There is no way around it. Let's just say, if there is a handful of false matches is better than looking through the full sheet manually (30-40 000 rows).

Comment: Ok in that case you can use [.Find/.FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) as  @Variatus suggested and if there are multiple matches then fill the cell with "Cold/Warm". This way you can simply filter on these and fix them manually. For this you will again have to maintain a database of 2 columns as I mentioned in the 1st comment. Col A with the Fruits/vegtables. ColB Will have Cold/Warmer. Then you code will loop through this database and search for the keywords in the your above image file.

Comment: Can you confirm the column name from the image above where the names are stored? I am trying to create a sample code to demonstrate something

Comment: The name is stores in column E.

Comment: Posted an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To demonstrate what I meant with a wildcard match:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
Dim Cold As Variant, Warm As Variant

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4")
Cold = Array("*strawberries*", "*raspberries*", "*lettuce*")
Warm = Array("*cucumber*", "*bell pepper*", "*tomatoes*")

With Application
    For Each cl In rng
        If .IsNumber(.Match(True, .IsNumber(.Match(Cold, cl, 0)), 0)) Then
        'Or: If UBound(Filter(.IsNumber(.Match(Warm, cl, 0)), True)) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Cold"
        ElseIf .IsNumber(.Match(True, .IsNumber(.Match(Warm, cl, 0)), 0)) Then
            MsgBox "Warm"
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

---

Alternatively, you could use regular expressions with word-boundaries:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
Dim Cold As String, Warm As String

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4")
Cold = "strawberries|raspberries|lettuce"
Warm = "cucumber|bell pepper|tomatoes"

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .IgnoreCase = True
    For Each cl In rng
        .Pattern = "\b" & Cold & "\b"
        If .Test(cl) Then
            MsgBox "Cold"
        Else
            .Pattern = "\b" & Warm & "\b"
            If .Test(cl) Then MsgBox "Warm"
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

You can also, match both in any case and see if it's supposed to be a combination of warm and cold.

Comment: This looks interesting. I will give it a try.

Comment: @Andreas, and if these lists get longer and you want to make it more comfortable writing your arrays you could use something like : `Cold = Split(Replace("*strawberries|raspberries|lettuce*", "|", "*|*"), "|")`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a perfunctory system that would return the information you want from a list of produce.

```
Sub GetStorageInstruction()
    ' 187
    
    Dim Veggie      As Variant
    Dim Storage     As String
    Dim Txt         As String
    
    Veggie = InputBox("Enter name of fruit or vegetable to store:", _
                      "Get storage instruction")
    Veggie = Trim(Veggie)
    If Len(Veggie) Then
        Storage = StorageInstruction(Veggie)
        If Len(Storage) Then
            Txt = "Store " & Veggie & " at a " & Storage & " location."
        Else
            Txt = "Sorry, I couldn't find instructions on" & vbCr & _
                  "storage of """ & Veggie & """."
        End If
        MsgBox Txt, vbInformation, "Storage instructions"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function StorageInstruction(ByVal Veggie As String) As String
    ' 187
    ' return vbNullString if not found
    
    
    Dim ListRng     As Range
    Dim Fnd         As Range            ' found match
    Dim C           As Long             ' column
    
    ' here items for "Cold" storage are in column A,
    '      items for "Cool" storage are in column B
    Set ListRng = Range("A:B")          ' adjust to suit
    Set Fnd = ListRng.Find(Veggie, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
        ' the return result is taken from the caption row (row 1)
        ' of the column in which a match was found
        StorageInstruction = Cells(1, Fnd.Column).Value
    End If
End Function
```

"Ordinarily", you wouldn't work with an InputBox because it's too error prone (typos) but with a validation list or combo box that is based on the same lists. But for the moment, if you are concerned about not finding "Bell peppers" (plural), consider either listing "Bell pepper" as well or modify the search to `LookAt:=xlPart`.

To make the above code work for you immediately, just type "Cold" in A1, "Cool" in B1 and a list of produce under each header. The code will return the header from the column where the item was found.

I see that you have now added a view of your worksheet. That is a much better base. Instead of the produce name, list a number from your columns C or D (whichever is unique), in my columns A and B, and enter that number in the InputBox. Once you implement that system you can modify the returned answer by using the number to VLOOKUP the product name so that the description appears in the answer along with the number you entered.

As an afterthought, the best way for you would probably be to just select the row you are interested in, click a button (or keyboard shortcut) and have the storage instruction pop up. But the presumption here is that you should be able to attach VBA code to your workbook.

Comment: I don't want to search for SKU. SKU can change, and new products could come in. I mean "broccoli" will always be broccoli, and it should always be stored cold, it doesn't matter what SKU it has or if it's sold in packs of two or chopped in pieces. That is why I "need" (prefer) a fuzzy word match.

Comment: I'm going to think about this solution. Not sure I can keep the list in a sheet. I can but not sure I want to. The benefit is that it's easier to maintain and update, but I have colleagues that keep renaming files/folders and/or moving/deleting stuff. And this list needs to be found all the time.

Comment: `And this list needs to be found all the time.` Then you will have to save it somewhere :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yeah... The problem is that people keep moving/deleting my stuff. I wish we had an IT department you could actually reason with. But sadly not. So the only fool proof way would be to keep the list within VBA.

Comment: @Andreas `So the only fool proof way would be to keep the list within VBA.` Then go with what @JvdV suggested :) You have both solutions at your disposal. OR use a hidden sheet in the file which contains the code :)

Comment: Consider placing your list in a `VeryHidden` worksheet. `VeryHidden`means that the user can't see the sheet and can't, therefore, unhide it and can't, therefore, make changes to it. The only way to get at a `VeryHidden` sheet is via the VB Editor window. If your people tend to search there you can password protect the VBA project which is separate from the worksheet or workbook protection.. Try to avoid having long lists in the code. Code is to manipulate data, not to store it.

Comment: I'll post a solution that allows you to just click on an item in your list and look it up by SKU number. - Half an hour.

Answer (score 2):

> No. Correct. I solved that with search for asparagus then search again in the same string for potatoes. But I know there will be false matches. There is no way around it. Let's just say, if there is a handful of false matches is better than looking through the full sheet manually (30-40 000 rows). – Andreas 1 hour ago

Here is an example of what I recommend. Feel free to go with other answers. If there are multiple matches then fill the cell with "Cold/Warm" as mentioend in the code comments below. This way you can simply filter on these and fix them manually.

**Basic Preparation to test this**

1. Create a master sheet in the file which has the code. Let's call it `MasterList`. The reason why we are doing this is so that it is easier to maintain and when you are distributing the code file, the masterlist is easily available. You can do version control on the file so that everyone uses the current version. Let's say the `MasterList` looks like this.

   [image]
2. Let's say the file (as shown in your image) is called `MyData.xlsx` and the data is in `Sheet1`. Feel free to change it in the code below. It looks like this

   [image]

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsThis As Worksheet
    
    '~~> This is the hidden sheet which has your master list in the file
    '~~> which has the code
    Set wsThis = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterList")
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim MasterList As Variant
    
    With wsThis
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        MasterList = .Range("A2:B" & lRow).Value2
    End With
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsThat As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Change this to the workbook where the data needs to be checked
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\MyData.xlsx")
    '~~> Change this to the workseet where the data needs to be checked
    Set wsThat = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim rngToProcess As Range
    
    With wsThat
        '~~> Find last row in Col E which has names
        lRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Identify your range
        Set rngToProcess = .Range("E2:E" & lRow)
        
        '~~> Insert a blank column for output
        .Columns(6).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End With
    
    Dim SearchText As String
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    '~~> Loop through the masterlist
    For i = LBound(MasterList) To UBound(MasterList)
        SearchText = MasterList(i, 1)
            
        Set aCell = rngToProcess.Find(What:=SearchText, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell
            
            '~~> Get the Warm - Cold - Warm/Cold Status
            aCell.Offset(, 1).Value = GetStatus(MasterList(i, 2), aCell.Offset(, 1).Value)
            
            '~~> Search again for multiple occurences
            Do
               Set aCell = rngToProcess.FindNext(After:=aCell)
        
               If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                   If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                   aCell.Offset(, 1).Value = GetStatus(MasterList(i, 2), aCell.Offset(, 1).Value)
               Else
                   Exit Do
               End If
            Loop
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

'~~> Common function to asign the values
'~~> If there are multiple matches then fill the cell with "Warm/Cold". 
'~~> This way you can simply filter on these and fix them manually.
Private Function GetStatus(MasterStatus As Variant, CurrentStatus As String) As String
    Dim newStatus As String
    
    If MasterStatus = "Cold" Then
        Select Case CurrentStatus
            Case "Warm": newStatus = "Warm/Cold"
            Case Else: newStatus = MasterStatus
        End Select
    ElseIf MasterStatus = "Warm" Then
        Select Case CurrentStatus
            Case "Cold": newStatus = "Warm/Cold"
            Case Else: newStatus = MasterStatus
        End Select
    End If
    
    GetStatus = newStatus
End Function
```

**Output**

When you run the above code you get the below output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to my earlier answer. Install the code below in a standard code module and make some arrangement to call it, perhaps with a keyboard shortcut or even a button on the sheet. Then simply select an item (anywhere in the list, no particular column) and run the code. You don't need to enter anything.

```
Sub Storage_Instruction()
    ' 187
    
    Const SKUClm    As String = "D"         ' change to point at the SKU column in 'Data'
    Const DescClm   As String = "E"         ' change to point at the Description column in 'Data'
    Const StgClm    As String = "C"         ' change to point at Storage Instruction column in WsList
    
    Dim WsData      As Worksheet
    Dim WsList      As Worksheet
    Dim SKU         As String               ' SKU number from row R
    Dim Desc        As String               ' Description from row R
    Dim R           As Long                 ' the selected row
    Dim LookUpRng   As Range                ' in WsList
    Dim Fnd         As Range                ' found match
    Dim Storage     As Variant
    Dim Txt         As String
    
    Set WsData = Worksheets("Data")         ' insert your data sheet's name here
    Set WsList = Worksheets("Storage")      ' change name to suit
    
    With WsList
        ' my list has an extra column for 'Description'
        ' the storage instruction is in column C (=StgClm)
        Set LookUpRng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, StgClm).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    If ActiveSheet Is WsData Then
        R = Selection.Row
        With WsData
            SKU = .Cells(R, SKUClm).Value
            Desc = .Cells(R, DescClm).Value
        End With
        Set Fnd = LookUpRng.Find(SKU, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Fnd Is Nothing Then
            Txt = "Sorry, I couldn't find instructions for the" & vbCr & _
                  "storage of " & Desc & "(SKU " & SKU & ")."
        Else
            Storage = WsList.Cells(Fnd.Row, StgClm).Value
            Txt = "Store " & Desc & " (SKU " & SKU & ") at " & String(2, vbCr) & _
                  String(8, Chr(32)) & UCase(Storage) & String(2, vbCr) & "temperature."
        End If
    End If
    MsgBox Txt, vbInformation, "Storage instruction"
End Sub
```

For the setup you do need to specify the 3 constants at the top of the procedure and the names of the two worksheets that are referenced.

The list is a simple copy of the SKU column from your big list. In my test I also copied the the descriptions. You may find that way easier to fill the 3rd column, which holds the words "Cool" and "Cold" (or whatever else you want) against each item. The middle column isn't used and not required y the above code.

According to your description, the 'List' sheet should be Very Hidden. In the VB Editor's Project Browser, click on the sheet, bring up its properties and set the `Visible` property to `xlVeryHidden`. The sheet can be made visible only by changing this property back to `xlVisible`. The property setting is saved when you save the workbook.